# Windows 10 System Crash Then Overwrites profile

Tags: user-profile, windows-10

So this has happened to me 3 times now.

We have about 25 computers running windows 10 enterprise. All domain joined, all using roaming profiles (fortunately). And in the last 2 months ive had this problem 3 times.

The user will experience some sort of system instability resulting in either a system crash or a manual reset.

*Upon restarting and logging in, windows 10 will experience an incredible amount of errors - all AppModel-Runtime errors (I don't see any profile related errors). But windows 10 will overwrite the entire profile and recreate all the local components.*

**I have never experienced this with a stand alone PC or prior to the 1511 Update. 
Just wondering if anyone has had this issue and resolved it.**

I would like to resolve this issue but have been unable to find any diagnostic information or related posts about this issue. Any information on what could possibly cause this problem is greatly appreciated. I remind you i am not new. I went through the event viewer to find diagnostics but there is no events logged until after the newly created user profile has been formed and AppModel-Runtime errors persist (as these apps have a different status code than expect, this is nothing to do with the profile creation). If you have experience what seems like the same issue, and have been able to diagnose the problem, can you please share your troubleshooting steps and where the useful information was found.

I have been keeping backups of all the user profiles so i am able to work around it but this requires a manual effort.